# How to Create a Custom Error Handling Class Without Writing Error Handling into Functions

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a class that does nothing but handle error.  Use the classes methods when calling functions so that the methods from the error handling class stop the execution of the function if user input is bad.

```
class Error(Exception):
    pass

class UserError(Error):
    def handle_even(number):
        try: number % 2 == 0    
        except: raise UserError.handle_even('error: odd number\n')
    def handle_odd(number):
        try: number % 2 != 0
        except: raise UserError.handle_odd('error: even number\n')


def take_even(number):
    print(number) #if user input is bad, this shouldn't execute

def take_odd(number):
    print(number) #if user input is bad, this shouldn't execute



take_even(UserError.handle_even(5)) # I expect this to print 'error: odd number'
take_odd(UserError.handle_odd(4)) # I expect this to print 'error: even number'
```

So, the output I want is:

```
error: odd number
error: even number
```

However, the output I get instead is:

```
None
None
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `try` block won't generate an exception because an expression evaluation was true/false, also your odd/even checking logic was wrong.

```py
class Error(Exception):
    pass

class UserError(Error):
    @classmethod
    def handle_even(cls, number):
        if number % 2 != 0:
            raise Error('error: odd number\n')

        return number

    @classmethod
    def handle_odd(cls, number):
        if number % 2 == 0:
            raise Error('error: even number\n')

        return number


def take_even(number):
    print(number) # if user input is bad, this won't execute

def take_odd(number):
    print(number) # if user input is bad, this won't execute

# This will raise an 'Error' exception (error: odd number)
take_even(UserError.handle_even(5))

# This will raise an 'Error' exception (error: even number)
take_odd(UserError.handle_odd(4))
```

You could handle these specific `Error` exceptions like so:

```py
try:
    take_even(UserError.handle_even(5))
except Error as e:
    print(e) # print 'error: odd number'

try:
    take_odd(UserError.handle_odd(4))
except Error as e:
    print(e) # print 'error: even number'
```

**Edit:**
Changing the methods as class methods per @NathanVērzemnieks recommendation.

Comment: You need to declare your methods as class methods (with `@classmethod` and `cls` argument) or static methods (with `@staticmethod`) to use them like this.

Comment: Good point! I've edited my answer. Thank your for the recommendation.

Comment: One more suggestion: right now there's no point in `UserError` deriving from `Error`. I would have these methods `raise cls(message)` instead.

Comment: Another excellent point. However, if the OP doesn't want to use class methods, he might get confused as to why the non-class methods isn't generating the exception as before. Thoughts?

Comment: I just noticed that the poster's code is raising `UserError`, not `Error`, so I think the change won't cause much trouble, and in any case it's a better practice. The poster's code must have been different from what they were testing, anyway - as it is it it would raise `TypeError: unbound method handle_even() must be called with UserError instance...` (since the methods are defined as instance methods) rather than returning `None` as described.

Comment: @KhalidAli I tried this and it's handling bad input properly but I can't get it to print proper input.  For example if I were to change the arguments in take_even with taken_even(UserError.handle_even(4)), I still get "None" instead of "4".

Comment: @Fingers You just need to add a `return statement` to the methods – edited my answer.